# Why do I get 'foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object'' when the object is type IList

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to iterate over a list that I grab by doing solutionInformation.GetType().GetProperties().GetValue(). But even though the type is an IList, I get an exception when I try to iterate over the value.

```
namespace NS
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    
    public class Accelerator 
    {
        public string AccName { get; set; }    
    }
    public class DeviceInfo
    {
        public int Ram { get; set; }
        public List<Accelerator> Accelerator { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class SolutionPods
    {
        public DeviceInfo DeviceInfo { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Solution
    {
        public List<SolutionPods> SolutionPods { get; set; }
    }

    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var acc1 = new Accelerator { AccName = "accelerator Name" };
            List<Accelerator> accList1 = new List<Accelerator>();
            accList1.Add(acc1);
            
            var devInfo1 = new DeviceInfo { Ram = 64, Accelerator = accList1 };
            
            var solComponet = new SolutionPods { DeviceInfo = devInfo1 };
            List<SolutionPods> SCList = new List<SolutionPods>();
            SCList.Add(solComponet);
            var solution = new Solution { SolutionPods = SCList };
            

            foreach (var solutionComponet in solution.SolutionPods)
            {
                var solutionInformation = solutionComponet.DeviceInfo;
                foreach (var solutionProperty in solutionInformation.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    var solutionValue = solutionProperty.GetValue(solutionInformation);
                    if (solutionValue is IList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("IList found");
                        
                        // System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NS.Accelerator]
                        Console.WriteLine(solutionValue);
                        
                        /*
                        /tmp/AFBHdRy49g.cs(64,43): error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
                        */
                        foreach (var s in solutionValue)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(s);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Setup Complete");
        }
    }
}
```

Am I not actually grabbing a list? Or do I need to convert the object into a different form so that it has an GetEnumerator property?

Comment: Please avoid use of `var` in example code when types are important. Clearly `solutionValue` *is not* `IList`, it is `object`. It is possible you have some other expectations -  using explicit types and clearly explaining why you expect this code to compile would imporve the question. Also re-read [mre] guidance on posting code - most of the code shown does not clarify or relate to the problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My problem was directly related to not understanding that the typing was important and that var definied my variable as an object. I am working on my C# as my background is mostly in python where you don't have to delcare variables so heavily.  I wasn't sure if my issues was related to how the classes were setup or if it was because .GetProperties().GetValues() which is why I included the example code that I was working with. But I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I'd recommend searching for some article "C# for python developers" - I'm sure there are some, if nothing good comes up in search - searching for  "C# for javascript developers" definitely brings sensible results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, once a variable is declared, it keeps the type it's declared as. In your case, the `var solutionValue` uses the inferred type of `object` because that's what [`Property.GetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-propertyinfo-getvalue(system-object)) returns.

The compiler does not implement type narrowing when it encounters a conditional like this:

```
if (solutionValue is IList)
```

However, you can use pattern matching to declare a new variable with the correct type:

```
if (solutionValue is IList solutions)
{
   ...
   foreach (var s in solutions)
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does a *static* type check that the value provided is (statically) an `IEnumerable`. An `object` is not. A `(IList)solutionValue` would be.

```
if (solutionValue is IList list) // joining a type test and a cast
{
    foreach (var s in list) // here list is an IList
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```